# Dealloc an NSObject using ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nsobject, dealloc

I have multiple view controllers with a strong reference to a subclass of NSObject.  Each view  controller allows the user to mutate this object in some fashion and then passes the object to the next view controller.  Once completed the user can commit these changes and start the process all over with a new instance of the NSObject subclass.  The problem I am experiencing is that some of the view controllers on the stack are retaining the reference to the committed instance.

I have tried using weak, and unsafe_unretained but that makes it difficult to pass the object between view controllers.

I basically need to dealloc an instance of the object once committed, so that any view controllers' reference to it will be nil.  However, ARC doesn't allow explicit calls to dealloc.

I can solve this using NSNotificationCenter or by using a delegate, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Any insight would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model object (the object that everyone mutates) should be owned by a central "Model" class. You can pass that around. It could have a method such as `currentRecord` or the like. That way, all your view controllers can either have a weak reference to the current record, or they could just ask the Model for it each time they need it. View Controllers should never "own" data objects.

This means that the view controllers can use KVO to observe when `currentRecord` changes. It alternately gives you an object that can provide notifications when things change. Your Model object can also potentially handle network or disk access (alternately, you can have a separate controller that also utilizes the Model and provides network or disk access). The key here is MVC. You want to separate the model classes from the view and controller classes.

Comment: So could this "central "Model" class" be considered somewhat more of a Model-Controller than strictly a Model? (Or perhaps we could call it "outer model"). And the stuff that the Model-Controller encapsulates could perhaps be regarded as the Model itself (or "inner model")? I guess I'm confused by your `"View Controllers should never "own" data objects."` statement. Do you mean view controllers should neither own outer nor inner model objects, or they should own only outer but not inner directly? If the former, then what owns the outer model to prevent its deallocation?

Comment: Excellent questions. In many systems, I would call this "Model" a "RecordManager" if it managed all instances of Records. I might call it "Model" or "ModelController" if it handled all model objects. It depends on the size of the system and its complexity. I might split the model from the model-controller if they were complex. View controllers should never "own" any of these things. The model can be created at the beginning and handed to VCs. Despite iMartin's comment, Singleton can absolutely be the answer. Dependency Injection (which is just an indirect singleton) also works.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob.  To give you a little more detail, the app uses Core Data and we do have a data store controller (where all CD code is centralized).  The NSObject that I'm referring to is not technically part of our data model.  It represents a list of changes that will be applied to an NSManagedObject.  Once those changes are applied it needs to go away.  I totally get what you are saying, but I would like to keep the VC's as self contained as possible (avoid sharing global state).

Comment: The key is that View Controllers are ephemeral objects. They only are certain to exist while onscreen. They cannot "own" persistent data.

Comment: @GabrielOrtega, I would still tend to let a central controller own that "pending" object. In previous systems, I've even stuck the pending object in Core Data so that it persists. But if you don't want any of these things, then during performSegue: or however else you hand things from one VC to another, you would need to nil your own reference. This is a more fragile solution IMO, and implies even more information leakage than a central model controller.

Comment: My last note is essentially the same as @NSGod's answer. It is not a bad solution; it's different and just not the way I generally do it because it's easy to forget in one of the VCs to `nil`. I don't like little things everyone has to remember to do.

Answer (score 3):

It's reasonable to have each view controller `retain` the object while they are working on it.

While view controller A is working with the object, it retains it. When it is finished and will pass it to B, B retains it, and then A sets its own reference to it to nil to resign ownership of it. This process continues until the final view controller commits the object, then sets its own reference to it to nil, which should cause the object to be deallocated.

Comment: Dude I like the name you picked. Totally awesome.

Comment: +1, It makes sense for View Controller to retain model objects, because it's working with them. The user is working with them. I usually don't reuse VCs for different model objects and I allocate new instance every time, so I have no problem with nullifying or deallocating.

Comment: Thanks NSGod.  Will that also work if the navigation is not linear?  Meaning I'm on make changes on view controller A, navigate to B, change my mind and go back A.  I'm guessing I would have to include that use case in the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

once committed , you just set the object to `nil`. ARC will automatically release it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override dealloc method in your view controllers and set the objects to nil there. So that, when the instance of your view controller goes out of scope, the dealloc is called and objects will set to nil. Do not call [super dealloc] .

Comment: This is done automatically by ARC. When you are deallocated, all your properties are automatically released.